# Toggle a button on Navigation Bar in SwiftUI & have it change appearance

Tags: swiftui, ios13, ios-navigationview

Using `SwiftUI`, I would like to have the ability to change the button on my `NavigationView` based upon some Bool value indicating if it should be **On** or **Off**.

[image]

This would behave similar to how with UIKit you can replace a bar button item on either side of the screen to show a different button & associated action upon clicking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to get it working with the following code, but I am not certain if this is the best way to accomplish it, so am open to improvement.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeList: View {
    @State var isOn = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(1 ..< 4) { index in
                Text("Row \(index)")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(verbatim: "Title"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.isOn = !self.isOn
                }, label: {
                    Text(self.isOn ? "On" : "Off")
                })
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The key pieces being:

- Using the `@State` [modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) on my `isOn` variable, which tells my interface to invalidate & re-render upon changes
- Having my `Button` action modify `isOn` &it can also support other actions if I need
- The ternary operator in my `Button` label that updates the `Text` (or an `Image` if I want) to reflect the correct appearance

Finally, how it appears in action:

[image]